# VSCode Error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed, The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l', '-c', 'ninja '" terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: esp32, ninja

I'm trying to run the example temp_sensor_monitor_main.c file for the espressif IDE and flash it to my esp32, but I'm getting this error with no clue how to fix it. I've scoured the internet and I either don't understand how to fix it or haven't found my specific issue. I'm very new to this so if anyone knows a solution, I would really appreciate a step by step tutorial. Thank you.

I tried installing ninja on VS code terminal and the error was still showing. I'm using a UART approach with a USB connection between my laptop and esp32wrover